# twitter-typeahead: Bloodhound prefetch does not recognize prepare or transform functions?

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

Using: typeahead.js 0.11.1 (typeaheadbundle.js)

I am trying to use bloodhound to prefetch multiple result groups and return them based on a result group selection. Without grouping (just supplying URL) the code works perfectly. When I try to add grouping by giving a prefetch with prepare, the prepare function does not get called.

Code that works (Prefetch with URL only) :

```
  var suggestionUniverse = new Bloodhound({
    initialize: false,
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch:'./suggestlist.json'
});
var promise = suggestionUniverse.initialize(true);//initialize and clear any existing cache.
promise.fail(function () { console.log('err, something went wrong :('); });
```

Code that does not work (Prefetch with prepare) :

```
    var suggestionUniverse= new Bloodhound({
    initialize: false,
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch:{
        url: './suggestlist.json',
        prepare: function (settings) {
            console.log("Called prepare");
            return settings; //Optional: Add filter for batchid?
        },
        transform: function(response) {
            console.log("Called transform");
            return response;//add batch filters needed to reduce response.
        }
    }
});
var promise = suggestionUniverse.initialize(true);//initialize and clear any existing cache.
promise.fail(function () { console.log('err, something went wrong :('); });
```

I don't see any messages in the console, either during initialize (Good, no error) or during the suggestion show (Not good, prepare or transform is not called). Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Doing more research on this topic, looks like the typeahead-bundle.js is putting prepare and transform to indentity functions for Prefetch. These are implemented in Remote

Comment: I am moving this as an issue in Github to see if I can help fix the same.  Github link: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1701

Answer (score 0):

Check your Debugger Tools and see if a request is actually being made to './suggestlist.json' and if it is successful.  I was having a similar issue and realized that my prefetch was cached, so the prepare and transform functions were never called.  Try adding 'cache: false' to the prefetch settings (then remove if desired if it starts working).